# How to set background color in devexpress XtraGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I want to set the background color of devexpress winforms grid.

This is the method i call.

On form load..

> LoadCodes(); - returns a dataset which is used in gridView rowstyle  method.
>
> gridView1.RefreshData();

```
private void gridView1_RowStyle(object sender, RowStyleEventArgs e)
{
  string code=string.Empty;
  for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
  {
    code = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["code"]);
    if (code.Trim() == ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["code"].ToString().Trim())
    {
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.WhiteSmoke;
    }
  }

}
```

How do i handle this or is there any other way to handle this?

> Issue: The code doesn't throw any error, however i don't see rows
> getting the background color automatically, after the form is loaded,
> however when i click on any row of the grid (after the form is loaded, grid data is visible), then i get to see the background color.

Answer (score 1):

you have to tell DevExpress which of the Appearance properties should take effect by setting it on `e.Appearance.Options`

In your case `e.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = true`

For details see: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressUtilsAppearanceOptionsMembersTopicAll

Note: When you have defined styles for `EvenRow` or `OddRow` you have to set `e.HighPriority` too (see: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridRowStyleEventArgs_HighPrioritytopic)

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to set the default colors for the GridView like below,

```
gridView.Appearance.Row.BackColor = Color.Black;
gridView.Appearance.Row.BorderColor = Color.Black;
gridView.Appearance.Row.ForeColor = Color.White;
```

Above we are setting appearance for Row, then do the same for SelectedRow, FocusedRow, FocusedCell and GroupRow. This will make the all rows have a black background with white foreground.

Now if you want to override the default colors for specific cells, override the RowCellStyle event, https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic